# Replacing first word (label) of every line in a text file (annotation files)-Python Code

Tags: python, annotations, label

I am still beginner with the Python and need to modify labels of my annotations with .txt format.
The .txt annotation format looks like below:

```
10 0.31015625 0.634375 0.0890625 0.2625
9 0.37109375 0.35703125 0.0671875 0.2015625
```

And I need to replace the first number (class number/label) as:

- 10-->7
- 9-->6
- 6-->5
- 11-->8
- 8-->5

  I have written the following code but still it is far behind a complete one and I am kinda stuck.

```
    replacements = {'6':'5', '9':'6', '10':'7', '11':'8', '8':'5'}
    
    with open('data.txt') as infile, open('out.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        for line in infile:
            word=line.split(" ",1)[0]
            for src, target in replacements.items():
                word = word.replace(src, target)
            outfile.write(line)
```

Comment: Looping leads to erroneous replacements.  For instance, if word = '11', it will get changed to '8' on one replacement, then the '8' will become  '5' in the following replacement.   Writing line is another problem (i.e. seem as input).

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to loop through all of the replacements. You can just check if the first word is in your replacements dictionary. I'm assuming you only want to replace the first word.

```
word, tail = line.split(" ", 1)
if word in replacements:
  word = replacements[word]

outfile.write(word + " " + tail)
```

Your code doesn't change `line`, i.e. changing `word` does not change line as it is a different value. In general, strings are immutable in Python (but not lists), so you can't change a string object through a reference. Operations on strings will return new string objects.